# Selecting Text through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, selection

I want to select text thats is on a Html page and make it BOLD, I am using the following Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >


function getSelectedText(){ 
    if(window.getSelection){   ;
        return window.getSelection().toString(); 
    } 
    else if(document.getSelection){;
        return document.getSelection(); 
    } 
    else if(document.selection){ ;

        return document.selection.createRange().text; 
    } 
} 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("*").live("mouseup",
    function() {
        selection = getSelectedText(); 
        alert(selection);
        if(selection.length >= 3) {

            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(selection, "<b>" + selection + "</b>") );

        }       
    }
); 
});

</script>
```

This Code works Fine But when the text is in two different paragraphs/ Div or if there is a link between the text then it doesnt seem to work.

How Could i Make it Work ?

Comment: How about somehow initiating a browser search (Ctrl+F) from javascript? But, I don't know how to do that from javascript.

Comment: You just wanna select the text or the additional tags too? And what is the purpose of just selecting it? It would help if you explained what do you want to do with the text.

Comment: @pea window.find(string)

Comment: That will work fine for obtaining just the text that is selected but will not tell you anything about the HTML elements that contain the text. What do you actually want?

Comment: @All - Its a Simple program, I just want the selected text to be Displayed on the screen .  But when Two different paragraphs are selected then This Code doesn't seem to work ...

Comment: @crowicked - I would like to select the additional Tags too....

Comment: @Adi how can one select two paragraphs? That's not technically possible with ordinary mouse. Anyway there's no such thing as `@All` you have to notify each member separately if you want his/her attention.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard :  I actualy mean , Like there is a Wikipedia's page. I want that When i click and Drag My mouse over 2 Paragraphs , Then the content of both the paragraphs is returned ( what ever is selected by the mouse Across the 2 paragraphs)

Comment: The Code that i have mentioned Above doesn't work when the Content selected is across two different paragraphs or if there is a Hyperlink some where in between the text that i have selected otherwise the Code works Fine for me.

Comment: Sorry what you have is the only thing browser offer to get selected text so unless I misunderstand something, what you're after is not possible.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard : I saw this website http://www.awesomehighlighter.com/ In this the text that is selected is highlighted ( Doesnt matter if the text is in same paragraph or if there is a link in between the selected lines ) It highlights the text , I want a feature like this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do some kind of highlighting of the current selection, using the built-in `document.execCommand()` is the easiest way. It works in all major browsers.

The following should do what you want on any selection, including ones spanning multiple elements. In non-IE browsers it turns on `designMode`, applies a background colour and then switches `designMode` off again.

**UPDATE**

Fixed to work in IE 9.

```
function makeEditableAndHighlight(colour) {
    var range, sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    document.designMode = "on";
    if (range) {
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    // Use HiliteColor since some browsers apply BackColor to the whole block
    if (!document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour)) {
        document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
}

function highlightSelection(colour) {
    var range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        try {
            if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
                makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour)
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // IE <= 8 case
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
}

document.onmouseup = function() {
    highlightSelection("red");
};
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/eBqBU/9/

Comment: I Could not get this to work ...  I called your function like this ====$("*").live("mouseup",
    function() {
        selection = highlightSelection(red) ;

Comment: @Adi: Works fine for me. You need to add quotes around "red". I've updated my answer with an example use, and a live example.

Comment: Wohh!!! Yahooo!! it worked !! it Worked!! :D Great Work!! One last question.. Is there a Way in which i could use my Own CSS for Highlighting , The code that I wrote up in that i could chage the CSS by the FOllowing line $(this).html($(this).html().replace(selection, "<span class='highlight'>" + selection + "</span>") );

Comment: @Adi: There's nothing to do that built into browsers. You need to iterate over the nodes within the selection and surround each with your span, which is fairly complicated to do in a cross-browser way. You could use my Rangy library and it's CSS class applier module to do this: http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule

Comment: @Adi: Yes, it's free. It's licensed under the MIT license, which is the same as jQuery.

Comment: Your Code is Perfect... How did you manage to select the text which are in different paragraphs and apply the CSS ?

Comment: @Adi: The essential steps are: 1. split text nodes at the beginning and end of the selection; 2. create an array of text nodes that are contained within the range and 3. surround each text node in a `<span>` (unless it's already contained in a span with the relevant class).

Comment: I tried to understand your Code but was Unable to... :) What i understood is that Through the RANGER object we will split the nodes into arrays and then <SPAN> code will highlight it... But how would we check that the class is Already Spanned ?

Comment: Sir, the code that you wrote up. Is there any way to add and Unhighlighting code to that ? Some sort of Undo thing ...

Comment: @Adi: Using the same function and passing it "inherit" works. http://www.jsfiddle.net/timdown/eBqBU/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
a=document.getElementById('elementID').innerHTML;
```

variable 'a' will get the string value of anything inside the element with an id 'elementID'.

Is this ok?

Comment: Sir, I would like to get the contents that i have selected by the mouse, For example a Wikipedia's page. I want that When i click and Drag My mouse over 2 Paragraphs (selecting text) that is returned.   The Code that i have mentioned Above doesn't work when the Content selected is across two different paragraphs or if there is a Hyperlink some where in between the text that i have selected.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need (based on your comments) can be found here: http://www.awesomehighlighter.com/webliter.js

I don't have time to extract the relevant parts but take a look for example in `Webliter.prototype.highlight` (just search for this in that file)

You can also use jQuery for example this plugin: http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: Sir , The Highlight link that you gave will highlight, based on all the values searched in the Document , While i want it to highlight the things that i selected.

Sir, Please Execute the Code that i wrote  :)

Comment: @Adi I think the person who gave you the code has better chance of figuring this out. :)

Comment: Its all experimental code... Searching Here and there adding and modifying made be get that code  :D